# C# Regex assistance with escape character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the below:

```
String RTFContent1 = @"\\htmlrtf {{\\*\\bkmkstart MyLink}\\htmlrtf0 \\htmlrtf {\\*\\bkmkend MyLink}}\\htmlrtf0 \r\n{\\*\\htmltag92 </a>}\r\n{\\*\\htmltag84 <a href=\sip: 3333@mySIPDomain.com\>}\\htmlrtf {\\field{\\*\\fldinst{HYPERLINK \sip:3333@mySIPDomain.com\}}";
String RTFContent2 = @"\\htmlrtf {{\\*\\bkmkstart MyLink}\\htmlrtf0 \\htmlrtf {\\*\\bkmkend MyLink}}\\htmlrtf0 \r\n{\\*\\htmltag92 </a>}\r\n{\\*\\htmltag84 <a href=\http://www.google.com\>}\\htmlrtf {\\field{\\*\\fldinst{HYPERLINK \http://www.google.com\}}";
String MyLink = "MyLink";

Regex regex = new Regex("bkmkstart.*" + MyLink + @".*?HYPERLINK.*?(\w+:[^\s\\]+)");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(RTFContent1);
if (matches.Count == 0) -> Always true!!!
```

When I use https://regex101.com/ to validate the regex everything works fine except the fact that the C# regex has doubled backslashes:

```
// Working Regex
bkmkstart.*MyLink.*?HYPERLINK.*?(\w+:[^\s\\]+)
// C# Regex with no match
bkmkstart.*MyLink.*?HYPERLINK.*?(\\w+:[^\\s\\\\]+)
```

The test is here: https://regex101.com/r/tZJGLE/2

Any second pair of eyes looking at this will be appreciated.

Comment: Your both regex working fine on my side. Just compiler changes single backword slash to double backword slash but on regex evalution time your both rgex treated as same for match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you get a match in the C# version with the doubled backward slashes? I really don't get it. I run VS in debug mode with a breakpoint after the regex. I copy the RTF value and the Regex Value in  https://regex101.com/. Remove the double slashes and get a match. In VS no match at all :-(

Comment: Yes, with only changes your input string to double quoted. I got same output that you want.

Comment: Ok. I narrowed down the issue. The RTFContent1 string is the result of Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(myDoc.RTFBody). The resulting string includes quotes and backslashes. If I do a .Replace('\\', ' ').Replace('\"', ' ') before sending the variable to the Regex then it works. Is there any more elegant way to get around this issue? The replacement is quite costly as the document is pretty long.

Comment: You are testing against a wrong string, not the one you have in the RTF file. There, you may see that single backslashes are used to define RTF commands. [Your regex FAILS to match the strings](https://regex101.com/r/rWEULQ/1) even in the regex tester. You must test against `var RTFContent1="\\htmlrtf {{\\*\\bkmkstart MyLink}\\htmlrtf0 \\htmlrtf {\\*\\bkmkend MyLink}}\\htmlrtf0 \r\n{\\*\\htmltag92 </a>}\r\n{\\*\\htmltag84 <a href="sip: 3333@mySIPDomain.com">}\\htmlrtf {\\field{\\*\\fldinst{HYPERLINK "sip:3333@mySIPDomain.com"}}";` with `@"bkmkstart[^}]*MyLink(?s:.*?)HYPERLINK\s+"(\w+:[^"}]+)"`

Comment: Hi Wiktor the Regex is fine if you remove the line break (\r\n) https://regex101.com/r/rWEULQ/2

Answer (score 0):

When using a string literal, you need to double the quotes.

```
String RTFContent1 = @"\\htmlrtf {{\\*\\bkmkstart MyLink}\\htmlrtf0 \\htmlrtf {\\*\\bkmkend MyLink}}\\htmlrtf0 \r\n{\\*\\htmltag92 </a>}\r\n{\\*\\htmltag84 <a href=\""sip:3333@mySIPDomain.com\"">}\\htmlrtf {\\field{\\*\\fldinst{HYPERLINK \""sip:3333@mySIPDomain.com\""}}";

String RTFContent2 = @"\\htmlrtf {{\\*\\bkmkstart MyLink}\\htmlrtf0 \\htmlrtf {\\*\\bkmkend MyLink}}\\htmlrtf0 \r\n{\\*\\htmltag92 </a>}\r\n{\\*\\htmltag84 <a href=\""http://www.google.com\"">}\\htmlrtf {\\field{\\*\\fldinst{HYPERLINK \""http://www.google.com\""}}";
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice that the string was not well formatted. I quickly copied and pasted an extract of the RTF document which is fairly long. It does not address the root problem which is the no match.

Comment: Running the code you provided with the modified strings returns one match. https://www.ideone.com/dyXYUx

Comment: This is a wrong answer: RTF group commands in real RTF file are escaped with a single backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue was related to the fact that the generated string contains \r\n char which are interpreted depending on how the string is loaded.
The solution was to include the Singlelineoption to escape them:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("bkmkstart.*" + MyLink + @".*?HYPERLINK.*?(\w+:[^\s\\]+)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```